# Google Cloud Shell machine showing no temp space available

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud.. I didn't realise the space available on Google Cloud Shell machine and ended up running docker-compose command which consumed a lot of space. Now shell machine keep returning me an error like this

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: no space left on device
```

I checked the usage size and it say 100% used..

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            9.8G  9.2G  9.9M 100% /
```

Can anyone help cleaning up this or way to reset it?

Comment: same here :( after running `docker build`, I run into a bunch of issues with _no space left on device_